# Calculating area of polygon bounding boxes

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate area of polygon bounding boxes and the coordinates (x and y of polygon vertices) are saved in mask variable. This is my code:

```
f = open('train_labels.json')
data = json.load(f)
mask = []
for i in data.keys(): # iterate over all images in dataset 
    for j in data[i]: # iterate over json to access points (coordinates)
        mask.append(j['points'])
        print(mask)
        area = (mask[:, 3] - mask[:, 1]) * (mask[:, 2] - mask[:, 0])
        print(area)
```

Error that shows me is: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

When I print mask, the output is:

```
[[[141, 199], [237, 201], [313, 236], [357, 283], [359, 300], [309, 261], [233, 230], [140, 231]], [[25, 13], [57, 71], [26, 92], [0, 34]], [[264, 21], [296, 0], [300, 9], [272, 31]], [[322, 0], [351, 25], [340, 31], [317, 9]]] [[[141, 199], [237, 201], [313, 236], [357, 283], [359, 300], [309, 261], [233, 230], [140, 231]], [[25, 13], [57, 71], [26, 92], [0, 34]], [[264, 21], [296, 0], [300, 9], [272, 31]], [[322, 0], [351, 25], [340, 31], [317, 9]], [[287, 71]]] etc...
```

So between tripple square brackets ...,[317, 9]]] [[[141, 199],... doesn't exist comma (,) and is that the problem? If is how can I solve this?

Comment: You're trying to use numpy indexing on a non-numpy list `mask`.  Either use normal list indexing, or change `mask` to a numpy array.

Comment: Tired make `mask = np.array([])` and then `mask = np.append(mask, j['points'])` and in the `area` put `mask`.
 output is: `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed`

Comment: Why `mask.append(j['points'])` and not `mask = j['points']`? Some 'polygons' in the mask have 4 '2D-points', some 8, the last one you listed in print of mask has only one point ... Your code doesn't take it into consideration and will run anyway into errors. If not because of bad syntax for indexing, then because of not existing index or other issues.  *You have to become first aware of what you have as data and then how to handle them to get what you want to achieve.*

Comment: Bounding boxes need to know the max, min of x and y of all points in the polygon. Your code does not take it into consideration too ... *You have to re-design and re-think what you want to achieve. Error message seem not to be the actual real issue of the code but only effect of failing logic behind the code.* So getting rid of Error messages won't give you the result you want to achieve.

Comment: Please provide what print(j['points']) gives in the first 5 loops iterations. The missing `,` between the ]]] [[[ is the result of subsequent print statements of mask. There should be a line brake between them, right?
Have you give the print of mask at fourth and fifth iteration in your question? Or at first and second?

Comment: Not `mask=j['points']` because it takes for every image all annotations, now one by one. 
In print I just take a couple of coordinates as example, didn't take all because it is tooooo long. 
In print I just extract some points, I don't know for what itteration because I have 5060 images and too many annotations (points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
        xy = list(zip(*mask[-1]))
        area = (max(xy[0])-min(xy[0]))*(max(xy[1])-min(xy[1]))
```

`mask[-1]` will get the last item appended to mask (if you need the mask storing all the items).

`xy` is a two element list with all x-coordinates in first element and all y-coordinates of the polygon in second element.

`area` of the bounding box goes respectively from min, to max of x and y coordinates. The 'polygon' can have any number of points, but at least one.

I suggest you choose another name for `mask` as the name 'mask' suggest a use as mask which is not the case. For example `polygons_points_xy` will better express what value is represented by the name.